# SPI appears broken Ubuntu core and Intel Joule

Tags: intel, ubuntu-core, snap

SPI does not work in CORE mode and classic mode (mraa), with Tuchuck board (J12 connector). Appears to be a driver issue. Has anyone had any success? Are there any release or beta plans showing SPI integration?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, Intel hasn't publicly released the tools necessary to enable SPI on the Joule just yet (they require an NDA, you can talk to them if you like). As a result, SPI isn't yet enabled on the Ubuntu Core image for the Joule (though work is ongoing).

Comment: Thanks for the info, can I get some clarity. Do you have  experience with the Intel Joule? Or do you work with Intel?  Do you have anything to support that SPI on the Intel Joule is not implemented. Have you tested SPI with Ostro, and or Ubuntu (desktop, or CORE)?

Comment: My only supporting evidence is [this conversation in #snappy on freenode](https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2017/02/01/%23snappy.html#t18:25).